# C++ coverage tool for QA personnel

Tags: tools, coverage

Background: Our QA organization is considering using NCover Collector to gather code coverage information for manual and automated GUI tests (this is a desktop application). NCover will only work on our .NET applications and components. 60% of our application is C++ and we would get a lot of value if we could obtain coverage numbers for the C++ portion of our code base.

Is there an equivalent of NCover Collector for C/C++ code bases?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple that we've used before:

- Bullseye:  http://www.bullseye.com/
- Cppunit: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/

Answer (score 1):

covtool.sourceforge.net is quite popular

https://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/ is a good options for windows